# Classification of properties of structures

Tags: big-picture, metamathematics, model-theory

Is there a sensible classification of the properties of structures with a given signature $\sigma$, e.g. graphs with $\sigma = \lbrace R \rbrace$?

For example like this:

1. properties defined by first-order
   sentences over $\sigma$ (with or without specific syntactical properties)
2. properties defined by monadic
   second-order sentences over $\sigma$ (with or without specific syntactical properties)
3. properties stating the existence of
   another structure (of the same kind
   or another) and a specific <strike>mapping</strike> relation
   to it
4. properties stating that a given
   structure invariant has
   a specific value
5. properties stating that a given structure invariant has a specific property

How can this list be expanded, can it be completed or can it never be exhaustive?

Comment: Read about sketches in Johnstone's book Sketches of an Elephant (second volume).  They give a hierarchy going *down* from your number (1) -- geometric logic, essentially algebraic logic (finite-limit theories), algebraic logic.  There are many variations.  There is undoubtedly no end to such classifications, both up and down from first order logic.

Comment: Rather advanced, but thanks.